# create a cron job in centos to hit http get url with authorization header

Tags: curl, cron, centos7

I want to create a cron job in centos 7 to hit http get url with some authorization header in it.

i preferring to create it as a curl command.
any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl -s -H 'Header-foobar: x' -H 'Header-base:y' http://domain.tld/path
```

or if it's *basic auth*

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl -s -u user:password http://domain.tld/path
```

(run curl every minutes)